# Uploading image into database, issue $_FILES is not working

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am trying to write a code to upload image along with some other information on to my mysql db. But I am unable to do it. The php code is not entering the "if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"]))" statement. I am not sure how $_FILES works. Below is my html code for the file input tag and then I have added the code of my php as well:

HTML:

```
    <form id="myForm" action="inventory.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" method="post" >
<div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="confirm" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image URL</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input id="photo" name="uploadedimage" type="file" class="required">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Below is the Php Code:

```
$item_code = $_POST['itemCode'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
 {
   if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
   switch($imagetype)
   {
       case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
       case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
       case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
       case 'image/png': return '.png';
       default: return false;
   }
 }


if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    echo "enter first if";

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    //$imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $imagename = $item_code.$ext;
    $target_path = "images111/".$imagename;


    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

        $query_upload="INSERT into 'inventory' ('item_code', 'price', 'description', 'image') VALUES 
        ('$item_code', '$price', '$description', '".$target_path."')";

        mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  

    }else{

       exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    } 

} 
else
{
    echo "command did not work";
}
```

Comment: `!empty($_FILES)` is enough

Comment: Still the $_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"] is giving me Undefined index error and the if (!empty($_FILES)) is returning FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Is your `$_FILE` empty?

If so, is your `php.ini` configured correctly to accept file uploads? You have a couple of directives that have to be configured properly.

1. [**file_uploads**](http://php.net/file-uploads) is fairly obvious. It needs to be set to true to accept file uploads.
2. [**upload_tmp_dir**](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) is temporary directory used for storing files when doing file upload. Must be writable by whatever user PHP is running as. Usually PHP will use the default system temp dir.
3. [**upload_max_filesize**](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) is the maximum size of an uploaded file. If your file is larger than that, it won't be accepted.
4. [**post_max_size**](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) sets max size of post data allowed and affects file uploads also. Should be set to a larger value than `upload_max_filesize`
5. [**memory_limit**](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate and also affects file uploading. Generally speaking, `memory_limit` should be larger than `post_max_size`.

If any of these settings is not configured properly you may get an empty `$_FILES` array.